# AJAX - origin policy is violated

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I want to test an ajax call locally. Is that possible, or do I need to use a server like xampp? It always says the origin of the ajax call is null and this is against the origin policy.

client locally: C:/index.html

```
httpRequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:4000"
               + "?data="
               + value, true);
 httpRequest.send();
```

node js server on port 4000

```
    server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'file:///C:/index.html'
  });

});
```

Comment: You need a server yes.

Comment: @putvande: He has one.

Comment: The `file://` pseudo-protocol can't be validated by CORS because the origin is `null` or similar. You'll need to access the page with `http://` as well. Also note that the origin won't include the path; just the protocol, hostname, and possibly port.